# 'str' object is not callable error while trying to create threads and set up a pipe between them

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pipe

I am trying to create two threads and set up a pipe to communicate between the threads. It is giving an error: 'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable'

I saw that the most common problem was that the arguments were not being passed as a tuple online but I fixed it. It's still throwing the same error.

```
# Create two threads and communicate between them using pipes
import os
#import random
#import string
import time
import threading
def task_for_thread1(r,w):
    os.close(r)
    write_obj=os.fdopen(w,'w')
    for _ in range(1000):
        char='a'
        os.write(write_obj,'Thread 1 writes: '+char)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    write_obj.close()
def task_for_thread2(r,w):
    os.close(w)
    read_obj=os.fdopen(r)
    while(True):
        char_read=read_obj.read()
        print('Received character',char_read,'from the pipe')
if __name__=='__main__':
    print('Starting operation in main')
    r,w=os.pipe()
    thread1=threading.Thread(target='task_for_thread1',name='Thread1',args=(r,w,))
    thread2=threading.Thread(target='task_for_thread2',name='Thread2',args=(r,w,))
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
```

```
And this is the output I get in the console.

    Starting operation in main
    18
    19
    Exception in thread Thread1:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\vivek\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "C:\Users\vivek\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
    Exception in thread Thread2:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\vivek\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "C:\Users\vivek\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I edited the code as per the comment.

```py
# Create two threads and communicate between them using pipes
import os
#import random
#import string
import time
import threading
def task_for_thread1(r,w):
    os.close(r)
    for _ in range(1000):
        char2='a'
        os.write(w,char2)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    os.close(w)
def task_for_thread2(r,w):
    os.close(w)
    read_obj=os.fdopen(r)
    while(True):
        char_read=read_obj.read()
        print('Received character',char_read,'from the pipe')
if __name__=='__main__':
    print('Starting operation in main')
    r,w=os.pipe()
    print(r)
    print(w)
    thread1=threading.Thread(target=task_for_thread1,name='Thread1',args=(r,w,))
    thread2=threading.Thread(target=task_for_thread2,name='Thread2',args=(r,w,))
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
```

But now I get the following error:

```
Starting operation in main
24
25
Exception in thread Thread1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vivek\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\vivek\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:/PythonScripts/multi_threading_pipe.py", line 11, in task_for_thread1
    os.write(w,char2)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Exception in thread Thread2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vivek\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\vivek\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:/PythonScripts/multi_threading_pipe.py", line 16, in task_for_thread2
    read_obj=os.fdopen(r)
  File "C:\Users\vivek\Anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 1015, in fdopen
    return io.open(fd, *args, **kwargs)
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

Anu pointers on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Pass the function, not the name of the function. (I.e. remove the quotes.)

Comment: Thanks.. This helps to get rid of the error but I am not able to write or read to the pipe.

Comment: Update your question then.